# Finding the MLE of $\theta$ where $\theta \leq x$

Tags: parameter-estimation

consider the following PDF

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x;\theta) &=&
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2\frac{\theta^2}{x^3} & \theta \leqslant x\\
0 & x< \theta; 0 < \theta
\end{array}\right.\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now the answer stats $X_{1:n}$ so the minimum of $X$, but this cannot be deduced from the answer via my normal method (log likelihood), how am I to approach this, and other questions like it?

Comment: " this cannot be deduced from the answer via my normal method " Yes it can. What you can't is just equal the derivative to zero and expect that this gives you the MLE. In general, the global maximum of a function is not necessarily on a critical point (you must check for points where the function is not differentiable, and -as is the case here- for the borders of the domain).

Comment: So in general, check for bounds within the domain. And don't expect all points to be differentiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: At what value of $\theta$ is the likelihood maximized keeping in mind that $\theta \le x_i$ for all $i$?

Comment: I would say that $\theta$ should be as high as possible. because $\sum [log(2)+log(\theta)2-3log(x_i) ] $is the log likelihood function. this would be higher if theta was higher. And seeing as $\theta \leq x_i$ it should be the minimum of $x_i$, is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.